# Issue while loading vmware fusion 3.0

Tags: osx-lion

I just got my new MBP this week. So my first endeavor is to configure windows 7/XP through vmware fusion. 
          SO i installed Vmware fusion 3 and then try to configure Win7, but the problem is that vmware fusion is just not able to load. A black screen with "play button" seem to appear and stay as it is. I've to eventually force quit the vmware fusion. So i suppose this is the problem with vmware fusion.

P.S : I'm new to OSX(OSX lion) hence I may miss some technical thing to take care off.

Please let me know if I could do anything in some different manner to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of VMware Fusion is 4.1.2. I've had great luck with it on OS X 10.7. Full-screen support is very nice, for example.

There is some support of Fusion 3 on Lion, as mentioned here:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003715

Did you install Windows 7 through VMware, or are you configuring a BootCamp install? One black-screen hang I have experienced is moving a VM that has 3D graphics support enabled, and Fusion not detecting this as it imports the settings for the VM. Setting 3D graphics support on for the imported VM resolved that issue for me.

Comment: Yes, i tried installing win 7 through vmware. And, how am is supposed  to play with this 3D settings. And, the screen I'm talking about is simple plan black screen with a play button in the center. I think vmware is not able to launch.